# Unable to Redirect to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In html file to redirect a page using Javascript i used like this

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
```

Its working fine. But when i tried in .aspx it is not working
Below is my code. Thanks in advance

```
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PageRedirect() {
       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PageRedirect()"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Its working is IE for me , but not in chrome.

Comment: Its not working for me in IE and Chrome but below change is working fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PageRedirect(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: Thank you working fine i want to know in detail can you send any reference link that useful for me

Comment: Try this too: <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PageRedirect();"/> (not sure). link: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp

Comment: When i kept **return false** its working fine otherwise not. Want to know why to mention return

Comment: return false prevents default action. default action in this case is postback to the server, which is prevented

Comment: Yes in the function also we can return false