# Javascript from C# code behind only refreshes in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

My site has an asp.net button to post values to an external website, which works properly in IE and Firefox. It redirects back to the same page in Chrome.

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<body onload=document.forms[0].submit();window.location=\"{0}\";>", "Dashboard.aspx"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"Form\" target=_blank method=post action=\"{0}\">", URL));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"fname\" value=\"{0}\">", FirstName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"lname\" value=\"{0}\">", LastName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"id\" value=\"{0}\">", ID));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"tier\" value=\"{0}\">", tier));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"promo_code\" value=\"{0}\">", promoCode));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"login_key\" value=\"{0}\">", hashedKey));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body>");
    }
```

Desired behavior is to open a new tab or window with the external site loaded, with the parameters passed via POST.

Current behavior is the page simply refreshes. Is this a known issue with Chrome? My guess is that it's blocking the javascript as it thinks it's being "injected".

Comment: check out this from SO [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245572/unable-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you've got a race between posting the form & changing the url.

The `window.location.href` is not needed. Submitting the form should be enough. Also you probably should quote those attributes correctly to see if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "quote those attributes correctly"?

Comment: This fixes the problem, however now the original page is empty and white. But adding a response.redirect later on in the code then invalidates the form post / new tab.